# Handlebars Custom Template for Twitter Typeahead

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, twitter-typeahead

I am using **Twitter typeahead** in my application,

My Requirement is, i have json with **three array of objects**, which i want to use in to populate **autosuggestion** on min character length of 3.

I have **handlebars template**, which i compile in my Twitter typeahead(***typeahead.bundle.min.js***),

the problem i have is the, div in which i am wrapping my **handlebars** template is also becoming part of auto suggestion i mean as in image i have higlighted, which i dont want it to happen [image]
Expected out put is without that highlighted div.

Please see the JS Bin link for my DOM Structure and JS code
http://jsbin.com/figuzin/edit?html,js,console

and The Json i want to use is 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/4m8e8

Please do share any sample code, where you have build **custom template from handlebars** for **twitter typeahead** and able to populate different set of array objects
something like this, the below image show suggestion with three different array of items.
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you looked at [the examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates)?

Comment: @whipdancer - yes. actually i have to populate three different array of data in 1 suggestion